# Any way to obtain square root of a number without using math.h and sqrt()?

Tags: c, math

I've written a program for class that uses MPI to perform Fox's Block Matrix Multiplication method.  I was able to do this by using the sqrt() function in , but in order to compile the program I'm having to type in "mpicc -lm -o ...".  Instructions for the hw state to compile the program using "mpicc -o ...", without the -lm.  I was just wondering whether there was a way to find the square root of a number (without having to write a separate program to do so).  If not, I'll just put the disclaimer in the comments at the top of my .txt file.  Thought this might be a good place to ask though.  Thanks!

Comment: You can do it using a Newton raphson type approach. Is well documented on the Internet. But there is probably a better alternative to writing your own implementation of sqrt, which is a crazy idea.

Comment: Ask your teacher, I highly doubt they would care about the math library...

Comment: Just create a Makefile and add a `LDFLAGS` variable and add to it whatever libraries you want.

Comment: You could also include a makefile or script that handles the compilation. You should try to make compiling your program as easy as possible for graders/teachers.

Comment: Or make a shell script that will do the work..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method uses successive approximations. It doesn't take many iterations. Because the value of `root` can dither, I check the convergence to a small error.

```
//#define MINDIFF 2.2250738585072014e-308   // smallest positive double
#define MINDIFF 2.25e-308                   // use for convergence check

double sqroot(double square)
{
    double root=square/3, last, diff=1;
    if (square <= 0) return 0;
    do {
        last = root;
        root = (root + square / root) / 2;
        diff = root - last;
    } while (diff > MINDIFF || diff < -MINDIFF);
    return root;
}
```

Or, you could do it more simply by iterating a fixed number of times

```
double sqroot(double square)
{
    double root=square/3;
    int i;
    if (square <= 0) return 0;
    for (i=0; i<32; i++)
        root = (root + square / root) / 2;
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an old computer graphics trick for computing 1/sqrt:
(original code from Quake III)

```
    float Q_rsqrt( float number ) {
      long i;
      float x2, y;
      const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

      x2 = number * 0.5F;
      y  = number;
      i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
      i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what is this?
      y  = * ( float * ) &i;
      y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
      //      y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed
        return y;
    }
```

You can read all about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

BTW, I suggest that you just use the compile flag...

Answer (score 3):

For this You can read [babylonian-method](http://mathlesstraveled.com/2009/05/18/square-roots-with-pencil-and-paper-the-babylonian-method/). Then with the help of this theorem You can find `sqrt()` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of square root function using Newton-Raphson method.

The basic idea is that if `y` is an overestimate to the square root of a non-negative real number `x` then `x/y` will be an underestimate, or vice versa, and so the average of these two numbers may reasonably be expected to provide a better approximation.

```
#define ABS(n) (((n) < 0) ? -(n) : (n)) /* Absolute function */
#define TOL 0.001 /* Tolerance */

float sqrt2(float x)
{
    float y = 1.0;
    while (ABS(x/y - y) > TOL )
    {
        y=(y+x/y)/2.0;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code give output upto 0.000001 so check this out.
 The Program limited to find between 1 to 1050000000.

```
    {
        int x;
        printf ("Enter number : ");
        scanf ("%d",&x);
        int i=1,j=1;
        float x0=1.0;
        float xn=1.0;
        for(i=1,j=1;i<x;i=i*10,j++)
            if(x/i==0)
                i=x;
        i=i/10;
        j=j-1;
        if(j>1)
        x0=j*power(10,j/2);
        int a;
        for(a=1;a<=10;a++)
        {
            xn=0.5*(x0+(x/x0));
            x0=xn;
        }
        printf("\nSquare root of %d is  %f",x,xn);

    }
     int power(int x,int n)
    {
        int pow=1;
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
            pow=pow*x;
        return pow;
    }
```